# How to test if a service is called from the component in angular

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a component which on init calls getAllUsers() method and getAllUsers() calls getAllUsersApi from my service. I want to test if both the calls are actually made.

Here are some snippets from my code:

**test.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.getAllUsers();
}
getAllUsers(){
   this.userService.getAllUsersApi('');
}
```

**test.service.ts**

```
getAllUsersApi(){
   return this.http.get('api/endpoint')
}
```

**test.service.spec.ts**

```
it('should call getAllUsers method on init'){
  spyOn(userService, 'getAllUsersApi');
  spyOn(component, 'getAllUsers');
  component.ngOnInit();
  expect(component.getAllUsers).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(userService.getAllUsersApi).toHaveBeenCalled(); // it fails here
}
```

But it fails here: `expect(userService.getAllUsersApi).toHaveBeenCalled();`

Can anyone please help me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason your test fails, is because your component spy `componentSpy` is actually replacing your `getAllUsers` function in your component with an empty stub and therefore your `getAllUsersApi` call will never happen. `and.callThrough` will set up a spy and make sure the original function is being called.

I would test it like this:

```
it('should call getAllUsers method on init', () => {
  // set up spies, could also call a fake method in case you don't want the API call to go through
  const userServiceSpy = spyOn(userService, 'getAllUsersApi').and.callThrough();
  const componentSpy = spyOn(component, 'getAllUsers').and.callThrough();

  // make sure they haven't been called yet
  expect(userServiceSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(componentSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

  // depending on how your component is set up, fixture.detectChanges() might be enough
  component.ngOnInit();

  expect(userServiceSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(componentSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Fabian. It helped.